# Delete a character in excel until the first character

Tags: excel, replace

I have data in a column that is structured like this:

> s1 ma(av) course title

And i want to delete everything up till and including the ")"
BUT sometimes in my data something like this occures:

> s1 ma(av) course title(extra info)

So if i do a find and replace with this "*)" it deletes everything.
Is there a way to delete everything up until the first ")"?

The result should be:

> course title(extra info)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately my Excel is in german only, but im sure you can translate the functions.

This should work:

```
=TEIL(A1;FINDEN(")";A1)+2;55)
```

The "+2" deletes the following whitespace.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question but how do i apply this to a whole column?

Comment: should be `=MID(A1,FIND(")",A1)+2,55)`

Comment: Paste the code in the first field. Mark the field. Doubleclick the small black square in the bottom right corner of the field.

Comment: Sorry again for stupid question (new to Excel) but if i paste it, it just replaces the text?

Comment: You need to paste the code in another column and edit the defined columns in the code. Take a look at this example: (https://abload.de/img/unbenanntdou6p.png)

Comment: hmm, try this instead: `=MID(A1;FIND(")";A1)+2;55)`

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Ijoq1yy.png This is what im getting now, i feel like i am close. I copied exactly what you wrote, but changed the cell numbers

Comment: What language is that "NAAM"? Its not english i guess. The function names like "MID" and "FIND" are different in other languages. If you are using danish for example u need to adapt them to the language you are using in your excel.

Comment: wow omg that was really stupid of me :) it's in Dutch. Thanks for the help, ill figure it out now.

Comment: =DEEL(G2;VIND.ALLES(")";G2)+2;55)

This was the answer, for anyone wondering. Cheers again mate!

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the number of characters you want to remove from the left string by changing the Number 10 in the formula

```
=RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-10)
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting!

Comment: The first bit is not always the same though:

Comment: sometime it's like this

jr-1 ma(av)
or 
ma(av)

Comment: Sorry for the wierd formatting and commenting, stackoverflow is new for me and the commenting section isnt very intuitive imo

Comment: did you find a solution?